# How do I print the values from a key in a HashMap on different lines?

Tags: printing, hashmap

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> channels = ...
for(HashMap.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry : channels.entrySet()) {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println( key );
            System.out.println( value );
            System.out.println( "" );
}
```

> What I am receiving is this
>
> 101
>
> [Great British Bake Off, Pointless, Sherlock]
>
> 24
>
> [Fury vs Wilder, F1 Monaco, Premier League]
>
> What I want is
>
> 101
>
> Great British Bake Off

> Pointless

> Sherlock

> 24
>
> Fury vs Wilder

> F1 Monaco

> Premier League

Answer (score 0):

You could either make another loop for the array or use a foreach() on it

as such:

```
 ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue() // You should (almost) never declare some variable as Object
 value.forEach(System.Out.println)
```

If you are new to coding it might be more readable to for another loop for each of the values